# expect(...).toBeBefore is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've been reading this book "Testing JavaScript Applications". Currently I'm stuck at *3.2.3. Custom matchers*. Using Jest Extended module but it's not working.

```
// inventoryController.js

const inventory = new Map();

const getInventory = () => {
    const contentArray = Array.from(inventory.entries());
    const contents = contentArray.reduce((contents, [name, quantity]) => {
        return {...contents, [name]: quantity};
    }, {});

    return {...contents, generatedAt: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(3000))};
}

const addToInventory = (item, quantity) => {
    if(!+quantity) throw new Error('Quantity must be a number');
    const currentQuantity = inventory.get(item) || 0;
    const newQuantity = currentQuantity + quantity;
    inventory.set(item, newQuantity);
    return newQuantity;
}

module.exports = {
    inventory,
    addToInventory,
    getInventory
}
```

```
// inventoryController.test.js
const { inventory, addToInventory, getInventory } = require('./inventoryController');

beforeEach(() => inventory.clear());
beforeEach(() => inventory.set("Cheesecake", 0));

test("inventory contents", () => {
    inventory
        .set("Cheesecake", 1)
        .set("macarroon", 3)
        .set("croissant", 3)
        .set("eclaire", 7);

    const result = getInventory();

    expect(result).toEqual({
        Cheesecake: 1,
        macarroon: 3,
        croissant: 3,
        eclaire: 7,
        //  CUSTOM MATCHER LOOSELY 
        generatedAt: expect.any(Date)
    });
});

test("generatedAt in the past", () => {
    const result = getInventory();
    const currentTime = new Date(Date.now() + 1);
    // const isPastTime = result.generatedAt.getTime() < currentTime;
    expect(result.generatedAt).toBeBefore(currentTime);
});

test("returned value", () => {
    //  DETERMINISTIC MATCHER
    const returnedValue = addToInventory("Cheesecake", 2);
    expect(returnedValue).toBe(2);
});

test("Cancels operation for invalid operation", () => {
    //  TEST CASE FAILS WHENEVER IT THROWS AN ERROR
    expect(() => addToInventory("Cheesecake", "test")).toThrow();
    expect(inventory.get("Cheesecake")).toBe(0);
    expect(Array.from(inventory.entries())).toHaveLength(1);

    //  WE USE IT TO MAKE SURE EVERY ASSERTIONS ARE RUNNING
    //  BUT ASSERTIONS COUNTING ISN'T ALWAYS A GOOD STRATEGY 
    //  SO WE USE ANOTHER ALTERNATIVE HERE
    /*
    expect.assertions(2);

    try {
        addToInventory("Cheesecake", "test");
    } catch (error) {
        expect(inventory.get("Cheesecake")).toBe(0);
    }
    expect(Array.from(inventory.entries())).toHaveLength(1);
    */
});
```

Now getting error in the test case `generatedAt in the past`.

I tried to resolve it by reading jest-extended's official documentation but it also seems to not work.
I think there might be a version issue or something wrong with config file. Let me share its details as well.

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-extended"]
    // globalSetup: "./globalSetup.js",
    // globalTeardown: "./globalTeardown.js"
};
```

Comment: If you want to use `setupFilesAfterEnv` directly you need to use `"jest-extended/all"`. That's also in the documentation linked below.

Comment: Tried this already mate. Then it was throwing the error for import statement :(

Comment: What error, and why didn't you mention it? Why ask the question about something that's not supposed to work, and not either the things that are?

Comment: I have mentioned it already. Read the jest-extended documentation and followed the same steps but didn't work anyway.

Comment: My point is that your [mre] is of something that's not _supposed_ to work. If you tried what the documentation actually says, give a [mre] **of that**, not just a vague description of _"error for import statement"_ in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://jest-extended.jestcommunity.dev/docs/getting-started/setup) you should also extend the `expect` matches in a  `setup` file.

```
// testSetup.js

// add all jest-extended matchers
import * as matchers from 'jest-extended';
expect.extend(matchers);
```

The `setupFilesAfterEnv` should point to this setup file instead of to the `jest-extended` library

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "node",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./testSetup.js"] // <-- link to setup file
};
```

Comment: Tried this already mate. Then it was throwing the error for import statement :(

Comment: what is the error it is throwing?